# How to address Firebase from an Arduino?

Tags: ssl, https, arduino, firebase

Background: I've a sensor hooked up to an arduino printing readings through the serial monitor. I want to log these in firebase.

I've done a bit of digging on this, and my research has shown me that an arduino simply can't handle the SSL needed to talk to firebase properly.

Any suggestions for workarounds? Checking SO and google's only turned up "it can't be done", but I figured I'd ask anyway. Any lateral thinking is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's true what google says: "it can't be done"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a php script I whipped together to solve for Arduino no https.
It's basically a form that GETs to the php script and then sends it off to your Firebase database. 
http->php->Firebase

https://github.com/robertcedwards/httpFirebase

*Make sure you add Heroku or your server to the whitelist of IPs that can post to Firebase

Answer (score 7):

If you figure out a way, let us (support@firebase.com) know.  That would be an awesome hack!

Some thoughts:

1. You might want to look into the [Spark Core](https://www.sparkdevices.com/) (available for pre-order).  They mention SSL support, though it's unclear to me what that means exactly.
2. You could proxy the requests through a server that can speak SSL.  For instance, you could run a tiny node.js service on an Amazon EC2 box that just proxies REST requests to Firebase (e.g. using [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy)).
3. If you're hardcore, you could try to get the Arduino talking to an external ethernet controller that has built-in SSL support (e.g. [this one](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/devices.aspx?ddocname=en542414)), but that's probably a big project. :-)

Longer-term, we might expose a non-SSL endpoint for Firebase requests that's specifically for this sort of low-end hardware use-case.  Ping us at support@firebase.com if you want to start a dialog.

Comment: I put it to some people here in the office with me, and we think adding a intermediary step of a heroku app with some data binding (like knockout js?) is our best bet. I'll come back with something when I solve it.

Comment: Here's the link to the library example I whipped together: https://github.com/robertcedwards/httpFirebase

Comment: Anything new with this? I'm preparing to build real-time arduino based measuring device and I'd like to post updates to multiple clients. I was thinking about firebase, but I'd like to avoid extra server in between. Do You guys have native solution without extra components?

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old question but visitors from google keep coming.

Have a look at this post: http://www.devacron.com/arduino-firebase/

Answer (score 1):

[EDITED]

These arduino libraries might help:

firebase-arduino

- https://github.com/googlesamples/firebase-arduino
- https://github.com/ed7coyne/firebase-arduino

To install it:
Download the zip file, go to Sketch>Manage Libraries>add .zip file

Now you have access to

```
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
```

and can begin using it with

```
Firebase.begin("example.firebaseio.com", "token_or_secret");
```

Follow the example at https://github.com/ed7coyne/firebase-arduino/blob/master/examples/FirebaseDemo_ESP8266/FirebaseDemo_ESP8266.ino